# Cannot find libglfw.h

Tags: xcode, glfw

I'm trying to work with glfw, and I've looked everywhere to find how to include in Xcode, but just about nothing works. This is my current setup:
[image: Xcode setup]

My main.cpp is:[image: Main.cpp]

As you can see, I tried to include libglfw.a but it can't be found. I've tried changing it .h, I've included the source code for glfw, I've tried everything I can think of and everything I could find online. Nothing ended up working. Do I need to include another framework or what?

Answer (score 0):

libglfw.a should be in `$HOME/code/glfw/lib/x11/libglfw.a` upon installation.

If it is try moving it to `lib/` rather than `lib/x11/`

If you need the `glfw.h` you'll have to move that as well

Comment: I just found this article: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=3931.0;wap2 which goes into more detail.

Comment: If you go to your terminal and type `sudo find / -name libglfw.a` it will go through your system and find all occurrences of the file.

Comment: Terminal didn't find it. Is there a way to find it in finder?

Comment: Well that command would reveal it if the file existed on your system/in the finder. Do you have the library installed? http://www.glfw.org/

Comment: I have it installed. However, it still didn't work. But, I found another way to do it.